force_authenticate and middlewares
I'm trying to write tests using APITestCase and the provided self.client.
I'm using self.client.force_authenticate to authenticate a user. It looks like it's handled in rest_framework.request.Request constructor, itself created from rest_framework/views.py(391)initialize_request(), so after the middleware has been executed.
If I brekapoint in a middleware here what I see:
(Pdb) p request
<WSGIRequest: GET '/api/admin/products/'>
(Pdb) p request.user
<SimpleLazyObject: <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x7f537e0aa9a0>>
(Pdb) p request._force_auth_user
<User: admin>

The ._force_auth_user placed by DRF is here, but .user is not here yet.
Is there a clean way to force_authenticate and have the request.user available during the middleware execution (at least after the AuthenticationMiddleware)?
